# How to handle varying data by one POJO

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to create a single POJO for the varying JSON data. Is there is a way to implement this by a single class only? and without writing Serializer and Deserializer?

ResultTwo Example:

```
{ "results": ["24","0","18","34","27"] }
```

ResultOne Example:

```
{
"results": [
    {
      "value": "2|2|5"
    },
    {
      "value": "2|3|4",
      "multiplier": 25
    },
    {
      "value": "2|3|5"
    },
    {
      "value": "2|3|4",
      "multiplier": 50
    },
    {
      "value": "1|1|4"
    },
    {
      "value": "3|6|6",
      "multiplier": 30
    }
]
}
```

What I've tried:

BaseResult

```
public class BaseResult { }
```

ResultOne

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ResultOne extends BaseResult {
//    {"value":"2|6|6","multiplier":25}
//    or
//    {"value":"4|4|4"}
    private String value;
    private Integer multiplier;
}
```

ResultTwo

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ResultTwo extends BaseResult {
    private String result;
}
```

ResultSerializer

```
public class ResultSerializer extends StdSerializer<BaseResult> {

    public ResultSerializer(Class<BaseResult> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(
            BaseResult value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider arg2)
            throws IOException {

        if(value instanceof ResultTwo){
            ResultTwo result = (ResultTwo)value;
            gen.writeString(result.getResult());
        }else if(value instanceof ResultOne){
            ResultOne resultOne = (ResultOne)value;
            gen.writeObject(resultOne);
        }else{
            throw new ClassCastException("BaseResult value doesn't have any known type: " + value);
        }

    }
}
```

ResultDeserializer

```
public class ResultDeserializer
        extends StdDeserializer<BaseResult> {

    public ResultDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public BaseResult deserialize(
            JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException {

        String content = jsonparser.getText();
        JsonNode node = jsonparser.getCodec().readTree(jsonparser);
        if(node instanceof ObjectNode){
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return objectMapper.treeToValue(node, ResultOne.class);
        }else{
            ResultTwo resultTwo = new ResultTwo();
            resultTwo.setResult(content);
            return resultTwo;
        }
    }
}
```

On parent class I've annotated this:

```
    @JsonSerialize(contentUsing = ResultSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = ResultDeserializer.class)
    private List<BaseResult> results = null;
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `class Results<T> { List<T> results; }`.

Answer (score 0):

@Kulsin -
In spring controller you can use Map<String, Object> as request body, which can entertain your both the requests-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
        public void testMethod(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> request) {
//access data using request reference.
}
```

Comment: I know it can be done this way, but we don't want to use "Object". We want to create a POJO for this.